# Variable initialization inside if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, variables, global-variables

I want to save datetime object of last message if some condition is True and then use this object outside if statement. There is a simple code showing what I need to do. Also, I do it inside class.

```
If "abc" in message:
   message_datetime = message.get_datetime()
else:
   if message_datetime == 01.01.2001:
     def func()
```

I tried to define global variable or inside class __ init __, but without result.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean — please provide a complee [mre].

Answer (score -1):

well first of all, youre checking if a string (`"abc"`) is inside a string variable (`message`) right? so how would that string variable have a get_datetime() method? is `message` an object or a string variable?

and you cant use more than 1 decimal points so wrap that number with quotes

correct me if im wrong, but from the looks of it, `message` is an object and you want to get its datetime value right? to access the string of the `message` object, it should be stored in `message.message` or something like that. and datetime functions (the ones that output numbers with more than 1 decimal) return strings because floats can't have 2 or more decimals.

also, your func() definition is missing a colon `:`

and since its empty, you have to put `pass` underneath it